# How to compress image from Facebook Page Plugin on PageSpeed Insights

Tags: wordpress, image-compression, google-pagespeed

I added a **Facebook Page Plugin** on my website and I am currently optimizing the site by checking it on [Google Page Insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http://www.fanntasticfishing.com/&tab=mobile) so under **Optimize images**
`Optimize the following images to reduce their size by 11KiB (20% reduction).` How can I optimize the images on the Facebook Page Plugin? is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Our company also has this problem, you could either:

- Contact facebook to fix it for everyone (Including us).
- Not include the facebook snippet if the google pagespeed scraper is found.

The second option worked for us.
(Code is from my job, I can't share that. And it will be patched if google finds it).